# How does Visual Studio measure the % Blocks coveraged in test unit?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, teamcity, code-coverage

When I click to run the unit tests with code coverage, it has a column showing the % of blocks coveraged.

I also use TeamCity to measure, and I noticed that they have different metric. I would like to know how Visual Studio measures. I did some calculations but I haven't figured it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Using Code Coverage to Determine How Much Code is being Tested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx)

> Code coverage is counted in blocks. A block is a piece of code with exactly one entry and exit point. If the program’s control flow passes through a block during a test run, that block is counted as covered. The number of times the block is used has no effect on the result.

Note:
A code block ends when it reaches a decision point such as a new conditional statement block, a function call, exception throw, enter, leave, try, catch, or a finally construct.

So basically the % is the number of used code blocks divided by total blocks excluding code block returns.

You can read about block definition here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block

I hope that give you the information you wanted.